# SQL DATABASE DUMP / TEXT PARSE

Tags: mysql, sql, text, textview, dump

can i dump a database to be like...
`(username).txt`
and then on it the password?

likes this at :
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNn1a.png) and this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJnCI.png)

or like at this...
put in a `.txt` file and then dump like that way?

Answer (score 0):

You have to externally encrypt your file.

As the resulting sql file is a text file. Use zip or rar to compress and cypher your data.
In more Detail for windows please search for other operating systems or other programs than 7zip

First make a backup

```
mysqldump --routines yourdatabase/schema > outputfile.sql
```

There are a lot of options, so check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html

Now start for example 7zip File Manager

Select the nackup dile outputfile.sql

And click on add

This dialog appears
[image: /zip archover]

Give your new compressed file a name. enter a password.

Slect sfx if your are not shure, if 7zip is installed on the maschine where you have to restore your database

Winzip and winrar have their own methods.

There are of course solutions, which you can use at a command prompt. see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5831/how-do-you-encrypt-data-while-performing-a-mysqldump

Comment: can you explain more how to do it? i'm new at thism sorry.

Comment: i added an example for 7zip

Comment: ty, i will try that @nbk